Typo 3 #1476107295 TYPO3\CMS\Core\Error\Exception PHP Warning: Undefined array key "ctrl" when trying to create a new record
When I am in the Typo 3 backend and try to hit Create new record in the list view I get this error: #1476107295 TYPO3\CMS\Core\Error\Exception
PHP warning: Undefined array key "ctrl" in /var/www/{Website}/vendor/typo3/cms-backend/Classes/Controller/NewRecordController.php line 471
I am using Typo 3 version 12.4.7 and PHP version 8.1.2 on Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS with Apache/2.4.52. I am running Typo 3 in composer mode. The whole project is based on an non public template by the german red cross (no support from that side so iam stuck on my own).
How can I fix this error, do I need to edit the code of the cms bachkend class or is it just something that is misconfigured in my install?
I tried completly restoring the template state (should work, was tested and is deployd by many sides) but that did not solve the problem.

the "templates" of the DRK are at least partially public available. So you might share the extension key.

@David wich key do you mean?

the key under which the "template" can be seen in the backend in the Extension Manager.

Do you mean drk_template? If not i am lost and dont realy know what do you mean

You might check if you've the latest version (12.4.0): https://gitlab.com/drk-intern/typo3-v9.5/drk_template/-/tree/12.4.0/Classes?ref_type=tags

Actually not. Will update later and see if that fixes the problem. My installation seems to be broken or cursed anyway. Hopefully the upcoming migration from my development system to the final web server will fix this.
Will keep this thread updated.

Consider that the fault could be caused perhaps by another extension, but an update of the drk_template is certainly advisable and useful anyway.

I just updated the whole package from drk and this also updates all other extensions. The problem is now fixed. I still dont know what caused the problems and the typo 3 backend still shows the version number from the extension of the old version, but all extensions seems to be up to date now.

About the version it's a bit strange, as the file ext_emconf.php includes the correct version: https://gitlab.com/drk-intern/typo3-v9.5/drk_template/-/blob/12.4.0/ext_emconf.php?ref_type=tags.

An update of all Extensions with composer fixed the Problem. Its still a bit strange, cause it should have worked with the old version, but i am happy it was a quick fix.


#1476107295 TYPO3\CMS\Core\Error\Exception PHP warning: Undefined array key "ctrl" in /var/www/{Website}/vendor/typo3/cms-backend/Classes/Controller/NewRecordController.php line 471

This error hints for a missing ctrl configuration of a TCA managed table. So you have to debug/look which table is requested and add the corresponding key to it. Looking at the code, not only the ctrl section but also the crtl -> title is required.
That means, the extension providing the record you are trying to add as new record has a invalid TCA configuration. Either missint in the extension or removed by an TCA Override of another extension.
You may fix that within any custom extension / sitepackage as TCA override,
fix it in your own extension or contact the 3rd party extension author to fix it there.
From provided error message it cannot be told which table / record is the trouble maker.

How can I check which extension is causing this error?

Based on the "record" you want to create you can search for it. You couly add a breakpoint there. I'd say we can make a core patch to avoid that error, but it would be empty then anyway. Does not help you on a short coming.

The thing is, it happens when I try to create any record, or to be more precise, before I can choose which type of record. At least when I want to add a record to the data folder of the drk template and also its subfolders.

Sure. It loops over all regeistered content elements, and one of had missing the key. But which one would only be revealed when debugging at that point. Regarding your own answer, updating 3rd party extension fixed that it's most likely that it has been revealed and fixed. Which one cannot be said with the provided information in the question post.
